# UIButton to be sent in php POST request

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have 3 UIButton on a single tab, what I am looking for is that for example if I select button1 and I push post button, it post it to the DB. Well, I have already done this by posting text through input fields, and now I would like to do the same for sending the buttons value.

Here is a snippet code on the way I sent post request to the server through input fields :

> ```
> if([[self.fieldOne text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.fieldTwo text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
>  [self alertStatus:@"Please fill all the form" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
>  } else {
> NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=%@&fieldOne=%@&fieldTwo=%@",[self.fieldOne text], [self.fieldTwo text]];
> NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/page.php"];
> ```

**The question :**

How to do like this send request for buttons ?

Comment: u need send request with text in the button?

Comment: No I need to send only the value of the button

Comment: you mean `button.titleLabel.text` or `button.tag`?

Comment: So theres your answer I suppose.

Comment: @Martol1ni, I didn't got you, what do you mean ?

Comment: use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"buttonValue=%d", button.tag]`

Comment: join your button tag in your post parameter then send the request

Comment: @iDev can you please explain clearly ?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, does not work with, it says "button" is undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=%@&fieldOne=%@&fieldTwo=%@&buttonTAg=%d",[self.fieldOne text], [self.fieldTwo text],button.tag];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, in this case it says : (use of undeclared identifier "button")